# Cannot get polls to show in url

Tags: python, django

I am following the django tutorials and so far whilst on task 3, I cannot get the polls to show on the url.

If I have followed the instructions properly and carefully, it should look like this:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

However, when I run the server it cannot find polls

[image]

Comment: Did you create an app inside your django project for polls? If yes, then please include in your post the `INSTALLED_APPS` from your `settings.py`.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula I have included the settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the image, you can see the message:

```html
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    1. admin/
```

Your project is currently pointing at the urls in the `mysite` folder, which is the app that contains the `settings.py`. You can verify this by checking the `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings.

Based on the url patterns in your `polls.urls`, your best option is to move `include('polls.urls')` in `mysite.urls`:

**polls/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

We're doing this [because](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs):

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

Remember: You shouldn't declare the root path in the same `urls.py` that is imported on the root path like how you declared `path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))` in your `polls.urls`. You're basically importing `polls.urls` in `polls.urls` this way.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense! I missed this part but I will remember it from your explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the step "Write your first view" from the tutorial

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

The next step is to point the root URLconf at the `polls.urls` module. In `mysite/urls.py`, add an import for `django.urls.include` and insert an `include()` in the urlpatterns list, so you have:

`mysite/urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```